# How to retrieve layouts of customs objects belonging to a managed package?

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, metadata-api, page-layout

I am trying to retrieve the `layouts` of all(standard + custom) objects from a test Enterprise org using package.xml manifest files. There are some customs objects that I have created on this org.

There is a managed package(SalesForece Google Ads,SFGA) installed in this org. This packages contains some customs objects also e.g

```
SFGA__Ad_Group__c
SFGA__Google_Campaign__c
SFGA__Keyword__c
SFGA__Search_Phrase__c
SFGA__Text_Ad__c
SFGA__Version_33_0_3__c
```

My package.xml manifest file tries to fetch layouts. File looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <types>
       <members>*</members>
       <name>Layout</name>
   </types>
   <version>25.0</version>
</Package>
```

In response I get the layouts of standard objects and the custom objects that i created myself. However I do NOT get the layouts of custom objects that belong to that managed package. How can I get the layout of custom objects that belong to a managed package?

Also, will I be able to change the layouts? I know I can change the layouts for standard ones and the ones that i created myself.

Comment: auny, my mistake, seems this does not apply to layouts. I can download these through eclipse. So you should be able to with ANT. Each package has its own package.xml...

Comment: Which API or method are you talking about? Can you elaborate on the usage of API?

Comment: You can use the *packageNames* attribute in your build.xml file to query the layouts for a managed package (e.g. SFGA). This will cause the objects and layouts to be downloaded from that package. You can then modify the layouts and upload your changes.

Comment: Did you mean to say `package.xml` when you said `build.xml`? So from your comment i take that changes can be done on layouts from 3rd party managed packages. I initially thought that it would not be possible

Answer (score 30):

To fetch objects from a managed package using the unmanaged package.xml, you need to explicitly call for each object, as the wildcard only retrieves objects outside a package.

To retrieve layouts you need to include the full (namespaced) object name before the hyphen, and the full (namespaced) layout name after the hyphen.

So for a packaged layout over a standard object you need to retrieve

```
<Object Name>-<namespace>__<Layout Name>
```

and for a packaged layout over a packaged object

```
<namespace>__<Object Name>-<namespace>__<Layout Name>
```

I have used the Salesforce for Social Media app as an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <types>
        <members>Campaign-sf4twitter__Campaign Layout</members>
        <members>Case-sf4twitter__SfSocial Case Layout</members>
        <members>Contact-sf4twitter__SfSocial Contact Layout</members>
        <members>Lead-sf4twitter__SfSocial Lead Layout</members>
        <members>sf4twitter__Fcbk_Page_Admin__c-sf4twitter__Facebook Page Admin Layout</members>
        <members>sf4twitter__Fcbk_Page__c-sf4twitter__FCBK Page Layout</members>
        <members>sf4twitter__Fcbk_User__c-sf4twitter__FCBK User Layout</members>
        <members>sf4twitter__Twitter_Account__c-sf4twitter__Twitter Account Layout</members>
        <members>sf4twitter__Twitter_Contributor__c-sf4twitter__Twitter Contributor Layout</members>
        <members>sf4twitter__Twitter_Conversation__c-sf4twitter__Conversation Layout</members>
        <members>sf4twitter__Twitter_Followers__c-sf4twitter__Twitter Follower Layout</members>
        <members>sf4twitter__Twitter_Scheduler__c-sf4twitter__Twitter_Scheduler Layout</members>
        <members>sf4twitter__Twitter_Search__c-sf4twitter__Twitter Search Layout</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
   </types>
   <version>27.0</version>
</Package>
```

If you retrieve profiles at the same time then these profiles will also include the layout assignments.

You can also use an `ant list` call to retrieve the names of all layouts to use in your package.xml with one major caveat. The list metadata call drops the second namespace, so you'll get `sf4twitter__Twitter_Search__c-Twitter Search Layout` instead of `sf4twitter__Twitter_Search__c-sf4twitter__Twitter Search Layout`

Comment: The problem is that I do not know the names of the customs objects and their respective managed packages in advance.

Comment: You should be able to use listMetadata to obtain a list of layouts.

Comment: <target name="list-layouts">
  <!-- Retrieve the contents into another directory -->
  <sf:listMetadata username="${sf.sbu}" password="${sf.sbp}" serverurl="${sf.sbs}" resultFilePath="Layout" metadataType="Layout" />
    </target>

Comment: The result will be a file that describes the name of each layout, even those in managed packages: FileName: layouts/... I recommend a Perl or Ruby script to parse the output into an XML file for you to copy/paste into your package.xml file.

Comment: You Saved my day, even Mavensmate has this bug, we can select the page layout, but it doesn't retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve all components if you know package name

```
<target name="retrieve">
  <sf:retrieve 
    username="${sf.username}" 
    password="${sf.password}" 
    sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" 
    serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" 
    maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" 
    retrieveTarget="/Users/mavensMate/" 
    packageNames="Zuora Quotes"/>
</target>
```

Script will return package.xml, where under namespacePrefix you can get prefix name and just append to all needed componets:

```
<namespacePrefix>zqu</namespacePrefix>

From

    <members>Quote__c-Quote Layout - Renewal V8%2E0</members>
        ...
    <name>Layout</name>
</types>

To

    <members>zqu__Quote__c-zqu__Quote Layout - Renewal V8%2E0</members>
        ...
    <name>Layout</name>
</types>
```