# Retrieving extended package object descriptors into Eclipse with Force.com IDE plugin

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, eclipse

On my development org, I have a certain package installed, containing several custom objects. I have added a few custom fields to some of those objects through the web GUI. I have tried to pull those changes into the SFDC Project in my local Eclipse workspace, but even after I refreshed the metadata components list, I can't find and select these objects for retrieval.

Does anyone know how I could retrieve these extensions to the packaged custom object?

Comment: Is it a Managed or Unmanaged package? Installed Managed Package components aren't accessible via eclipse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To retrieve the managed package objects along with your custom metadata, you have to manually add the objects you want to retrieve to your package.xml file. For example, to retrieve a custom object, you might already be retrieving the Account object like this:

```
<types>
    <members>Account</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

You simply need to add the namespaced object name to this list. This is the "API Name" visible on the object page in the Salesforce UI

```
<types>
    <members>Account</members>
    <members>packagenamespace__CustomObject__c</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

If you just want to retrieve the fields that you are adding to that object for subsequent deployment, you can specify them in a CustomField type

```
<types>
    <members>packagenamespace__CustomObject__c.MyField__c</members>
    <name>CustomField</name>
</types>
```

Remember that the CRUD / FLS rules for any profiles that you are retrieving will include this object / field.

Please also see my response to this similar question about layouts [How to retrieve layouts of customs objects belonging to a managed package?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13852/how-to-retrieve-layouts-of-customs-objects-belonging-to-a-managed-package?rq=1).

This technique applies generally to most (all?) objects in the metadata API.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know that managed package object data, even user added custom fields, is available via anything other than the UI. Perhaps the Tooling api (and therefore the dev console) has access.