# Eclipse Losing Custom Fields

Tags: ide

I'm trying to build a deployment package using the Eclipse IDE. Several times, I go through all the fields I want to push and check them. When I hit OK and it refreshes from the server, none of my fields get pulled down. If I go back in, I can check them off again and it sticks for a little while. Eventually, they get left out of the components again.

Has anyone else seen this and know what is causing it or a work around? So tired of clicking.

Comment: I haven't moved a lot from development to production with Eclipse, but I didn't ever go down to the level of specifying fields.  I just selected the objects to transfer, and the fields seemed to get dealt without any work on my part.  I'd thought this was one of the advantages of the IDE.  How do you build your package?  Perhaps I stumbled onto a different method?

Comment: We don't select all fields because sometimes the dev sandbox has fields we aren't ready to promote. Selecting the whole object can also push validation rules and other changes. I want to be sure of what is getting pushed.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel:
I happen to come across your question as it's something I'm running into as well.  I happen to find this thread which was very helpful!  I was able to get it to work and figured I'd share with you in case it's still a question.

[Retrieving custom fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18467/retrieving-extended-package-object-descriptors-into-eclipse-with-force-com-ide-p)

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel: Instead can you try manually editing the package.xml and adding the CustomFields.
once you add the fields, click on save and then refresh from server.

Let me know if you were able to retrieve the fields. If not then it is a serious error.

Comment: I'm sure that will work to retrieve the fields once. The problem is that if I go in and edit the metadata then they sometimes disappear from package.xml. I haven't spent a lot of time on this since I switched to using MavensMate to build my deployment package.