# View Page Layout Assignments using MavensMate

Tags: mavensmate

Is it possible to retrieve layoutAssignments from profiles using MavensMate?

Judging by [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/14421/10720) answer, it looks like it should be.

But a search of my profile's metadata doesn't return any results & the only profile elements that seem to be retrieved are Apex Class assignments & user permissions (nothing related to objects i.e. Accounts).

[image: Search Results]

Based on the comments on [this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br9l) idea, it looks like I can simply retrieve the Profile object & find the assignments there.

[image: Page Layout Assignments Search Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

In order to view Page Layout assignments, you need to add the page layout to your project.

To do this select desired layouts and associated profiles in the new/edit project UI (or manually modify your package.xml).

*Answer from [this](https://twitter.com/joeferraro/status/832266298944057344) tweet, from Joe Ferraro @joeferraro.*